# When I run the Jmeter script, it's gives same output in the response data.But I have passed different input in req body that is also gave same output

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

For example there are 4 data in my csv

Test1,
Test2,
Test3,
Test4

When I pass "test1" as input in request body it will give "test4" as output in the response body.

Even when I pass "test3" as input it will give "test4" as output in the response data.

Even i have add http.cookie manager that is also not able to resolve this issue.if anyone provide the solution that would be great help for me...

Answer (score 0):

The question is not having much information.

Although, If you feel that it is due to caching - you can add Http cache manager component.

The response is something processed by the server/application. If you are returned with the same output for all the requests even though with different inputs. then, it is worth checking with the dev team for an advise

Answer (score 0):

1. If it can be reproduced using a real browser (or other application) - it's the system under test defect which needs to be fixed
2. If it can be reproduced only with JMeter and real browser (or other application) works fine - it means that you're not sending the same request as the browser does. Cross-check the requests originating from browser and JMeter using an external sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), identify the differences and amend your JMeter configuration accordingly. Pay attention to everything:

   - [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) including the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)
   - [Request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#request_context)
   - Request body

   More information: [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)

Comment: Dmitri, I have checked what you mentioned.There is no difference in request body and request headers data.i am passing same value in the script. Manually application is working fine. While run the script I'm facing same issue whenever i pass different input it gave same output in the response data..is there any way to clear this issue..

Comment: There is a "way to clear this issue" and I informed you about this "way". If you cannot figure out the differences yourself update your post with the sniffer tool output for JMeter and the browser.